# Tramp ssh connection inside eshell with gpg key

Tags: tramp, eshell, ssh, gpg

In my dotfiles I have the following setup to make ssh connections using my gpg key:

`.bash_profile`:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```

`.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

and calling `ssh-add -l` shows me my correspondig gpg key.

This does obviously not translate into tramp/eshell.
I tried setting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable inside `.config/emacs/eshell/profile`:

```
(let ((ssh_auth_sock (shell-command-to-string "gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket")))
(setenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ssh_auth_sock))
```

but this does not work and `ssh-add -l` only displays the error

```
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct way of getting this setup working inside tramp/eshell?

Comment: What is the value of the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable in the shell? Does it have a newline at the end of it? Does the socket filename on disk have a newline at the end of its name?

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback, no there is not a newline at the end of the value: `/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh`

Comment: Are you sure? What do you get if you type `ls $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` into eshell?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this is the output: ```~ $ ls $SSH_AUTH_SOCK 
/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
: No such file or directory```

Comment: I see a space after the end of the file name and before the colon that starts the error message. Either `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` has a space after it, or it has a newline and StackExchange mangled it because this is a comment rather than an answer. Either way, this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Yeah it's a newline it got mangled in the comment, but why is this a problem, in shell it is just working fine

Comment: I just tested `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh ssh-add -l` and it is working, what can I do to prevent eshell from inserting a newline into my env var?

Comment: Eshell is not inserting a newline into anything :P

Comment: Just found this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21901/why-is-there-a-newline-in-the-result-of-shell-command-to-string, thanks for pointing me into the right direction, if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it as the right answer

Comment: I am in the middle of writing one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we determined in the comments, `ssh-add` cannot open the socket file because that value of the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` has a newline in it. This newline is coming from your call to `gpgconf`. Every well–behaved program will ensure that the final line it prints ends in a newline character so that your prompt always ends up at the start of a new line. In this case that is perhaps unfortunate, because what you wanted it to print was not a well–formed line of text but a filename. Luckily removing the unwanted newline character is not hard. Incidentally, you should check the man page for `gpgconf` as there is an additional level of encoding here that could trip you up in the future, but which I will ignore for the purpose of answering this question.

As you found, there are [a number of ways](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21901/why-is-there-a-newline-in-the-result-of-shell-command-to-string) to remove this extraneous newline character after calling `shell-command-to-string` and before putting it into the environment. I like this one, possibly because I learned Perl at an early age:

```lisp
(defun chomp (str)
  "Chomp tailing whitespace from STR."
  (replace-regexp-in-string (rx (* (any " \t\n")) eos)
                            ""
                            str))
```

You could use it like this:

```lisp
(let ((ssh_auth_sock (chomp (shell-command-to-string "gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket"))))
  (setenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ssh_auth_sock))
```

Comment: For the records, the upcoming Emacs 28 has a new function `string-chop-newline`.

Comment: I used `(car (process-lines "gpgconf" "--list-dirs" "agent-ssh-socket"))` at tthe end

Comment: That’s a good choice.