# Why does shell command insert a newline in the output buffer?

Tags: shell-command

I have this code:

```el
(with-output-to-temp-buffer OUTPUT_BUFFER
  (shell-command
   (format "unzip -p %s %s | cat" ZIP_FILE_NAME LOG_FILE_NAME)
   OUTPUT_BUFFER OUTPUT_BUFFER))
```

I read a .log file from a .zip file and insert its content in a temp-buffer.

I can't understand why, if the log file is "empty" (0 byte) the temp-buffer size is 1. I.e. it seems that shell-command inserts a newline in the temp buffer.

Can I prevent this?

Comment: What makes you think it does that? AFAICS it does not: `  (shell-command
   "cat /tmp/does-not-exist 1>/dev/null 2>&1"
   "OUTPUT_BUFFER" "OUTPUT_BUFFER")` writes nothing to `OUTPUT_BUFFER`, as you can check by saving it and doing an `ls -l` on it. Maybe you are fooled by the exit status it reports in the echo area?

Comment: I tested with `buffer size` and moving cursor in the temp buffer. Maybe because "Shell commands usually terminate their output with a newline" https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21906/15606?

Comment: Just evaluating `(with-output-to-temp-buffer "test")` already produces the size of 1. You can try to find out what happens by expanding the macro using `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`, however, that did not make me any wiser. But I am not sure why you are using `with-output-to-temp-buffer`, you could just use `(shell-command
   (format "unzip -p %s %s | cat" ZIP_FILE_NAME LOG_FILE_NAME)
   OUTPUT_BUFFER OUTPUT_BUFFER)` directly, for the exact same effect... except of the mysterious 1 buffer size

Comment: @dalanicolai I used `with-output-to-temp-buffer` because i want "always" the output buffer to be displayed. It doesn't happen "if the output is short enough to display in the echo area". If my.log file is empty `shell-command` doesn't displays the output buffer.

Comment: Ah okay, I was not aware of this shell-command behavior indeed. In that case I would probably just, in the 'shell-command', pass (one of) the output buffers wrapped in a `pop-to-buffer`, e.g. as follows `(shell-command "ls" (pop-to-buffer "out") "out")`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline that the OP is worried about has nothing to do with `shell-command` or the command it executes (whether that command produces output or not - which in the case the OP describes, it does not).

The OP's case confuses the issue because he uses the same buffer in three different places: as the buffer used by `with-output-to-temp-buffer` and also as the buffer where the stdout and stderr of the command will end up.

Let us dispense with the command first. If you create a zip archive `foo.zip` that has (among other things) an empty file `foo` in it and you try to extract it, its stdout and stderr are both empty:

```shell
$ unzip -p foo.zip foo | wc
0 0 0
$ unzip -p foo.zip foo 2>&1 | wc
0 0 0
```

(piping into `cat` is superfluous in any case). So the command produces *NO* output.

Next, `(shell-command "unzip -p foo.zip foo" "some-buffer" "some-buffer")` leaves the buffer empty: no newline added. So "Shell commands usually terminate their output with a newline" is not the answer in this case.

@dalanicolai in his comment identified the culprit: `with-output-to-temp-buffer` does the following according to its doc string:

> Bind ‘standard-output’ to buffer BUFNAME, eval BODY, then show that buffer.

Note that the `standard-output` stream has nothing to do with the stdout of the command that `shell-command` executed. It is usually used for `*Help*` buffers where

> ... it binds
> ‘standard-output’ to that buffer, so that output generated with
> ‘prin1’ and similar functions in BODY goes into the buffer.

So using it in this case is probably a misunderstanding of what it really does on the part of the OP. But it is nevertheless what adds that final newline into the buffer. Since we have dispensed with both the command itself and `shell-command` as possible culprits, let's take a simpler example as suggested by the doc string above:

```el
(princ "foo")
```

That outputs three characters (no newline) to the `standard-output` stream. Now try:

```el
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "FOO" (princ "foo"))
```

The buffer contains *four* characters: the macro has added a newline.

To dig further, let's expand the macro call:

```el
(macroexpand '(with-output-to-temp-buffer "FOO" (prin1 "foo")))

---> (let*
    ((old-dir default-directory)
     (buf
      (with-current-buffer
          (get-buffer-create "FOO")
        (prog1
            (current-buffer)
          (kill-all-local-variables)
          (setq default-directory old-dir)
          (setq buffer-read-only nil)
          (setq buffer-file-name nil)
          (setq buffer-undo-list t)
          (let
              ((inhibit-read-only t)
               (inhibit-modification-hooks t))
            (erase-buffer)
            (run-hooks 'temp-buffer-setup-hook)))))
     (standard-output buf))
  (prog1
      (progn
        (prin1 "foo"))
    (internal-temp-output-buffer-show buf)))
```

So the macro calls the function `internal-temp-output-buffer-show` on the buffer. You can see that it is the culprit:

```el
(with-current-buffer "FOO"
   (erase-buffer)
   (princ "foo" (current-buffer)))
```

The buffer size of `FOO` is 3. But with:

```el
(with-current-buffer "FOO"
   (erase-buffer)
   (princ "foo" (current-buffer))
   (internal-temp-output-buffer-show (get-buffer "FOO")))
```

the buffer size is now 4 because of the added newline. Digging into `internal-temp-output-buffer-show`, there is a hook that is run at the end: `(run-hooks 'temp-buffer-show-hooks)` and the hook includes the function `help-mode-finish`. Finally, `help-mode-finish` calls `help-make-xrefs` and this outputs a newline:

```el
          ...
          ;; Delete extraneous newlines at the end of the docstring
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (while (and (not (bobp)) (bolp))
            (delete-char -1))
          (insert "\n")
          ...
```

That's how the newline gets added.

The moral of the story is that `with-output-to-temp-buffer` is the wrong macro to use: it's a special-purpose macro, meant to populate buffers that are frequently rewritten (like the `*Help*` buffer), so using it in other cases is fraught with dangers. @dalanicolai's comment:

> But I am not sure why you are using `with-output-to-temp-buffer`, you could just use `(shell-command    (format "unzip -p %s %s | cat" ZIP_FILE_NAME LOG_FILE_NAME)    OUTPUT_BUFFER OUTPUT_BUFFER)` directly, for the exact same effect... except for the mysterious 1 buffer size.

is spot-on.

EDIT: in response to the OP's comment about displaying the output buffer of the shell command always, one can do something like this:

```el
(let ((foo (get-buffer-create "FOO")))
  (display-buffer foo)
  (with-current-buffer foo (erase-buffer))
  (shell-command "echo baz" foo foo))
```

@dalanicolai's suggestion of `pop-to-buffer` doesn't quite work, because it makes the popped buffer be the current buffer, which you *don't* want to do in this case. Depending on your needs, you can e.g. make this into a function where you pass in the command as a string, mark the buffer read-only as `with-output-to-temp-buffer` does, erase it (as I do) or leave the previous contents and move to the end before running the next shell command, etc.

Comment: Excellent analysis.

Comment: I used `with-output-to-temp-buffer` because i want "always" the output buffer to be displayed. It doesn't happen "if  the output is short enough to display in the echo area". If my`.log` file is empty `shell-command` doesn't displays the output buffer.

Comment: See the edit in the answer.

Comment: I used `save-selected-window` combined with `pot-to-buffer` to restore the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

"Shell commands usually terminate their output with a newline" may well be the answer -- although on my GNU/Linux system I cannot reproduce the issue for your specific example.

Speaking generally though, the `shell-command*` functions naturally give you all of the output from the shell, and that might include a trailing newline.  If you want to bypass the shell, there are more direct ways of running processes.  See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Processes` and the "synchronous processes" and "asynchronous processes" nodes in particular.  I've just updated my answer in the related Q&A you'd found to cover one of those options: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21912/454

Alternatively (and also covered by that same linked answer), you can run a shell command which will suppress the newline.  I use `printf` for that:

```
(shell-command-to-string "echo foo")
"foo
"

(shell-command-to-string "printf %s foo")
"foo"

(shell-command-to-string "printf %s \"$(echo foo)\"")
"foo"
```